# W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera 1: Service not available

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-permissions

I know that this question has been asked before, however I tried all the solutions. None of them worked, I have the permissions in the android manifest and I also tried to ask for them manually. I tried releasing the camera, but nothing seems to be working.

I get a toast that my permission was granted when requesting manually, however when I go to the settings > myapp> permissions it is grayed out.

I am trying to access the camera and I really need help.

The camera app its self works fine, so the camera works.
And it detects the camera.
and I am on an emulator if that makes a difference.

Also most of this code is from the android docs themselves.

Please help me, 
Thanks!

```
package com.example.edonfreiner.siddur;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraView extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);




        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }



        if (checkCameraHardware(this)) {
            new CameraPreview(this, getCameraInstance());
        }

    }




    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    }



    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;

        try {

            c = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            Log.d("Camera", "there is an error with the camera "  +e.getMessage() );
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }


    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Log.d("Camera", "there is a camera");
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.d("Camera", "there is no camera");

            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }


}

class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        mCamera.release();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```